# Is there a script to remove this sign " in text?

Tags: scripting, text-object

I have 100 individual text objects, is there a script that will help me get rid of quotation marks in texts all at once?[image]

Comment: You can try using a macro software, to enter ' edit mode>press backspace>press 'home key" >perss delte>enter object mode. 
and bind these macro to a keybind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this python script:

```
import bpy

texts =  [ o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.type=='FONT']

for text in texts:
    text.data.body = text.data.body.replace("\"", "")
```